# UITableView Cell Label truncates on scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uikit

i have a tableview which displays a custom created cell. The issue is that the label in my cell gets truncated everytime i scroll. Even if i give my label a big width it still truncates.

This is my cellForRowAt:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as? CoronaStatisticsCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    let currentCountry = searchedCountry == nil ? countrySections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] : searchedCountry![indexPath.row]
    cell.configure(country: currentCountry)
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    return cell
}
```

This is my label which gets truncated in my cell:

```swift
private lazy var casesStaticticLbl: UILabel = {
    var lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 20)
    lbl.textAlignment = .left
    return lbl
}()
```

In the setSelected method i set my views:

```swift
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    layer.cornerRadius = 10
    countryLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(countryLabel)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        countryLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        countryLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        countryLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10),
        countryLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)
    ])

    var casesSV = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [casesLbl, casesStaticticLbl])
    var deathsSV = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [deathLbl, deathStaticticLbl])
    var recoveredSV = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [recoveredLbl, recoveredStaticticLbl])

    for sv in [casesSV, deathsSV, recoveredSV] {
        sv.axis = .vertical
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sv.spacing = 10
        sv.alignment = .leading
        addSubview(sv)
    }

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        casesSV.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryLabel.leadingAnchor),
        casesSV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
        casesSV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20),

        deathsSV.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
        deathsSV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
        deathsSV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20),

        recoveredSV.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -30),
        recoveredSV.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: countryLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
        recoveredSV.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -20),
    ])
}
```

This is the initial label

[image]

after scrolling:

[image]

I think theres an issue with my stackviews because if i only add the label to the cell nothing truncates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't play with constraints in setSelected... Also can you post entire cell code..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering your question based on the given contexts.

First off, Abhishek's comment is kinda agreeable. I would say you can definitely play with the constraints in the `setSelected` method, BUT not adding subviews. This merely comes from my personal preferences.

The only time you add subviews and set their constraints is in your init method `override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)`, but to reiterate, you can definitely toggle constraints in your `setSelected` AND also in your `cellForRow`.

To address your problem, given your current contexts in your question, you can add an **explicit width** as constraint. If you are stacking labels in a stackView, you must provide at least one explicit height or width constraint.

---

Lastly, take heed ⚠️ that Apple (App Store) and Google Play Store won't accept your app about

**COVID-19**

UNLESS you are from health organization. This is to prevent misinformation.